# Best way to refresh external data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My application uses much data from external sources. This data must be updated regularly.

I use the following approach for each table with external data when it's time to update.

1. Create new table, populate it with data, create indexes.
2. Delete existing table and rename the new one.

   ```
   BEGIN TRAN
     SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
     SET XACT_ABORT ON;
     EXEC ('drop table TableWithExternalData')
     EXEC sp_rename 'new_TableWithExternalData', 'TableWithExternalData'
   COMMIT
   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
   ```

During that, in application logs I can see errors like:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.TableWithExternalData'.

or

> Invalid object name 'dbo.TableWithExternalData'.
>   Could not use view or function 'dbo.vSomeView' because of binding errors.

What should I do to update external data without errors?

**UPDATE**

Reasons for using this method were the following.

1. It is "official": used by SSDT when generating table change scripts. SSMS uses the same method, but without setting transaction isolation level.
2. It works very fast, without long-living locks. Unfortunately, I have no info about changes in the datasource, and some of the tables are rather big. Full join for changes, or just truncate && insert is slower.
3. It is simple to implement and support. In rare cases of schema changes I can just add a column to the newly imported table, and after the scheduled data refresh I have the new column in production.

But it produces runtime errors in application using the database, so I need some other approach.

**UPDATE 2**

Slightly modified code works.
But still the question is: is that the optimal solution for external data refresh?

Reason of runtime errors: other transactions waiting for object_id, not object name; after table is deleted, there is no more object with the old ID.

Solution: do not delete the old table in the same transaction, but rename it.

More info: http://www.sqlnotes.info/2011/12/02/sp_rename-causes-lock-leaking/

```
BEGIN TRAN
  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
  SET XACT_ABORT ON;
  EXEC sp_rename 'TableWithExternalData', 'old_TableWithExternalData'
  EXEC sp_rename 'new_TableWithExternalData', 'TableWithExternalData'
COMMIT
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
EXEC ('drop table old_TableWithExternalData')
```

Comment: why no just use `truncate table` and then import ?

Comment: This seems like a huge x/y question. Why did you settle on that approach? Why completely replace the table each time? Why not e.g. only delete and reinsert the data that could possibly have changed (e.g. within an edit window)? Or even just all of it as Squirrel said. It's not at all clear why you do this dance with the 2 tables instead.

Comment: See question update.

Comment: Just commenting to say that I came across this post and it was super helpful. We have a similar scenario (table has X million rows, need to add a column, insert the old rows, insert new data) where we don't want to do any DDL to the existing table AND it would take an excessive amount of time to add columns, indexes, data etc. Whereas, doing a bulk copy and then rename is extremely fast in comparison. We had the same issue dropping the old table in the procedure but I found this post and we can just handle the drop in another process. Was really tearing my hair out there for awhile!

Comment: Also, might want to check out `ALTER TABLE... SWITCH`. We were also testing using that approach. Might be useful to others in a similar situation.

Comment: Just FYI, truncating an external table doesn't seem to be supported with Serverless SQL in Azure yet.  sp_rename isn't supported either so it seems like this approach wouldn't work in a Serverless SQL context.  Hopefully there's another way.